# One click behind

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have the following code which should be getting the text from a span within the selected jQuery tab, but it always seems to be one click behind.  i.e. if I click tab1, it shows nothing, if I click tab2, it shows the text from the span which was within tab1.  tab3 will show tab2's span and so on.

Not sure what I have done wrong, but here is the code I currently have:

jQuery:

```
$('[id^="tab"]').live('click', function() {
    alert($("li.ui-tabs-selected span").text())
});
```

HTML:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active" id="tab_group_44">
    <a href="#ui-tabs-2">
        <span>span content 1</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" id="tab_group_48">
    <a href="#ui-tabs-4">
        <span>span content 2</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" id="tab_pg_1">
    <a href="#ui-tabs-6">
        <span>span content 3</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Tab code:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    cache: true,
    ajaxOptions: {
        success: function(){
            $(".column").sortable({
                connectWith: '.column',
                start: function(e, ui){
                    ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
                },
                revert: true,
                opacity: 0.7,
                forcePlaceholderSize: false,
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                handle: '.btnWidgetDarkMove, .btnWidgetLightMove, .btnWidgetBrightMove, .btnWidgetGrayMove, .btnWidgetOtherMove',
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    var that = this;
                    var column = $(this).closest("div").attr("class").split(" ");

                    if( $(that).closest("div").attr("id") !== "column_4" ) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/ajax/save_homepage_widget_order.aspx',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { strTab:$("li.ui-tabs-selected").attr("id"), strColumn:column[1], strItems:$(that).sortable('serialize', {key: 'item', attribute: 'class', expression: /(\d+)/}) },
                            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                                //console.log(xhr.responseText);
                            },
                            success: function() {
                                //should use a return value here to make sure move has been saved
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }
            });


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you aware that [live is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com)? Unless you're using an ancient version of jQuery you should be using on (1.7+) or delegate. Also, why are you passing a jQuery object to jQuery (`$($())`)?

Comment: My guess is that the li is selected after your function is executed.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `$($('[id^="tab"]'))` and not this: `$('[id^="tab"]')`?

Comment: Either perform a setTimeout to wait until the update happens, or use a built-in method of the plugin that is meant for this purpose.

Comment: @KevinB, what is the built in method meant for this purpose?

Comment: I would consider the `tabselect` event the built-in method meant for performing something when a tab is clicked. Keep in mind that the event has two parameters: event, and ui. Inspect the properties of the ui object and it should contain both the previous panel and the next one. From that, you can obtain the id and then backtrack to the a and then the li based on the a's href if the ui object doesn't contain a direct reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab select is probably occurring after your click event, resulting in your experienced behavior.  Depending on how you set up the tabs, you may want to use the [tab select event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#events):

```
$( '[id^="tab"]' ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
  alert($("li.ui-tabs-selected span").text());
});
```

You can also try initializing the select function when you create the tabs:

```
...
cache: true,
select: function(event, ui) { 
    alert($("li.ui-tabs-selected span").text());
}
```

Update:
The issue you are experiencing may be stemming from the fact that the jquery class is not being set correctly.  Instead try to access the selected tab directly:

```
var selected = $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected" ).children('span');
alert(selected.text());
```

Comment: watch out there's a bracket missing on right side of selector

Comment: Tried this and it is still 1 click behind.  Before anyone asks, I double checked that I saved the changes, and I cleared the browser cache too.

Comment: @oshirowanen Can you post the code you use to initialize the jquery tabs?

Comment: @GrailsGuy, that works much better, but only the first time each tab loads.  How would I get this to work each time a tab is changed/selected?  I do need that cached tab option enabled, to prevent tabs from re-loading all the content again and again, and also to temporarily preserve the users selections in any given tab.  If I click on a tab which has already been clicked on and loaded, I don't get the alert.

Comment: @oshirowanen Updated with one more attempt.

Comment: @GrailsGuy, I will give this a try tomorrow.  Thanks for the help.